# Bootstrap 3.0 : Logo center alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have following code  and problem is that logo is not center aligned see code below

```
 <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 logo">                 
     <a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>" class="navbar-brand">
        <img  src="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>images/logo.png"   alt="<?php echo SITE_TITLE; ?>" title="<?php echo SITE_TITLE; ?>" border="0"  class="img-responsive center-block"/>
     </a>
</div>
```

so image is still not aligned left , for  navbar-brand i have following styles

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

how to make logo center when  it gets to  tabs/ mobile sizes

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you few days ago. Try to change your CSS for this:

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vzaear6b/)

Comment: should it be inside  media query or straightaway ?

Comment: This just centers `.navbar-brand` inside its container. The `col-md-8 col-sm-6` etc. classes are selected by media queries, so I don't think you need any new ones. It really just depends on whether you want something specific to happen inside this element for different devices.

Comment: I never heard about media query. But I think the "transform: translate(...)" changes according the device, because we are using percentages. So I think you can use it straightaway

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do it this way:

```
.navbar-brand {
  max-width: 200px; /* max width of your logo */
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: block;

  padding: 15px 5px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

And to image inside a link add class `img-responsive`. This way image will be scaled on smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float` from your navbar brand when it's less than 768px width using media query and change image display to block with proper margins like this:

```
.navbar-brand {
      float:none;
}
.navbar-brand img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's a  jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/38/

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 logo">
```

In bootstrap every page is divided into 12 columns.

This code says: for this div, make it 12 columns wide in extra-small screens, 6 columns wide in small screens, and 8 columns wide in medium and large screens.

So I'm not surprised that this will make the logo not centered (unless on extra small screens).

Comment: there is another div parralel to this one that is   <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

Comment: What does that matter for the alignment of the logo? In any case, it would probably be better if you would add all the code necessary to reproduce the problem to your post.